# How to convert gettext .mo file into .po file

Tags: python, translation, gettext

Is there any way to convert a .mo file into a .po file source, when the .po file is no longer available? I need to edit the content of a .mo file but I don't have the .po file. Is it possible?

Answer (score 52):

```
msgunfmt [path_to_file.mo] > [path_to_file.po]
```

Comment: It doesn't work well on files with accent characters..

Answer (score 7):

Under Windows and with recent [Poedit](https://poedit.net) 2.2.4 installed:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Poedit\GettextTools\bin\msgunfmt.exe" file.mo -o file.po`

To re-create the .mo file:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Poedit\GettextTools\bin\msgfmt.exe" file_edited.po -o file_new.mo`

Answer (score 6):

You can solve this problem by using  [polib](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/polib) to decompile .mo files.

Comment: An explanation on how to use it would be great...

Answer (score 6):

With installed [poedit](http://www.poedit.net/download.php) you can use:

START -> RUN (cmd)

/program files/poedit/bin/msgunfmt ab_AB.mo > ab_AB.po